# Plotting Data points away from the curve

Tags: matlab

im trying to compare data sets in MatLab, and in the figure im only able to place data tips along the curve but the data set im comparing with does not match my curve (hence the comparison). Is there anyway to plot data points anywhere on the plot or do they have to be somewhere along the curve?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a better description of what you mean? Or provide an image illustrating it?

Comment: With "data tips" do you mean [those](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you meant...

```
load data1.dat % your curve
load data2.dat % Comparison

figure(1)
hold

plot(data1(:,1),data1(:,2),'k-') % You plot your curve

plot(data2(:,1),data2(:,2),'ro') % you plot you points for comparison
```